# PayPal Rest API Update transactions

Tags: paypal

I am using the PayPal Rest API to implement PayPal into my website.  The flow for my site is below.

1. Users selects PayPal to pay
2. Create payment in code
3. Send to PayPal to approve
4. Sent back to Step 2 of my order process
5. User can update the shipping method or apply a coupon code
6. User Submits the order

As you can see the amount and details of my order can be changed after I create the initial payment in Step 2 of my process.  Also a user could update items/amounts on their order as well.

How do I update the transactions of a payment after it gets approved?

Answer (score 0):

you should use Payment authorization:

PayPal Authorization & Capture is a settlement solution that provides increased flexibility in obtaining payments from buyers. During a traditional sale at PayPal, the authorization and capture action is completed simultaneously. PayPal Authorization & Capture separates the authorization of payment from the capture of the authorized payment.

Authorization & Capture is for merchants who have a delayed order fulfillment process and who typically make a $1 USD authorization at checkout. It enables merchants to modify the original authorization amount due to order changes (such as taxes, shipping, or item availability) that occur after the buyers place the initial order. This chapter discusses the authorization and capture process and provides steps to help you authorize, capture, reauthorize, and void funds.

[Paypal doc](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/authcapture/)

---

you need to impelemnt instant update callback:

Here is how the Instant Update API works

When a buyer logs in to PayPal, the PayPal server calls your callback server with the buyer's default shipping address, which is stored in the PayPal system.
**Your callback server responds with the shipping options available** for that address, **along with any insurance options and tax adjustments on the order**.
PayPal displays this information in the cart review area so buyers can choose from the options.
The buyer's final choices are returned in the GetExpressCheckoutDetails response.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECInstantUpdateAPI/

hope this helps you

Comment: I don't want to use authorization.  This will go through as a sale at checkout.  The main thing is how do I update the items for a payment when the documentation says I can only update the amount?

Comment: you should submit items to paypal api only at the end of your checkout process and not before.

Comment: I have seen other sites send you to PayPal right away to enter your payment info and address information.  From there you are sent back to the original site and can still change things.  This is how it needs to work for me too.

Comment: please check this page, did you implement the same workflow ? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/

Comment: This is what is used to be and it worked fine.  However, we aren't sending the user to a receipt page after they approve the PayPal payment.  We are just sending them back to the website.  From there they could continue shopping if they want.

Comment: got u now, i've update the post, i think that implementing linstant update will allow you to update order after approval